# Mute command with database discord.py

Tags: mysql, discord.py

So in a regular mute command say, for example, the bot is getting an update, the mute command is left at its last point never unmuting the user! So I created a database and I stored the user_id that is currently muted and the datetime as the **final unmute time**, *also stored the guild's id*.

When I, for example, start the update, the mute is saved to the database to, later on, be pulled from the *on_ready* event. I then pull the values and then I do `discord.utils.sleep_until(dateime #aka the final unmute time)` and when it is done, unmutes the user.

**Here's the problem:** How can I get the guild's id, which is stored in the database, and take away the muted role in the guild taken from the database (since the server aka "ctx" is no longer a thing)?

Language - Python,
Database - mysql

```py
+----------------------------------------
|user1 |datetime(of the unmute)|guild_id|
+----------------------------------------

mute - inserts the above info^^^

def on_ready():
     print("ready")
     selects the values
     discord.utils_sleep_until(datetime of unmute)
     take away role in guild
```

If my current method is not the best, I am of course open to better suggestions.

Comment: Please include some code so we can see what you have done so far!

Comment: This is more of a conceptual question we didn't want to get into coding without knowing if it's possible this way, but something like above^

Comment: `How can I get the server's/guild's id(which is stored in the database) and take away the muted role in the guild gotten from the database(since the server aka "ctx" is no longer a thing!)` - Is NOT a conceptual question. It is about how to code something/how something works. You can indeed get the `guild` out of a database if you stored it when giving the role to a member. Therefore, we need to know how your code looks/ how you store all the things.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing this:

```
# load guild
guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)

# load member of the guild
member = client.get_member(member_id)

# remove role from the member
member.remove_roles([mute_role])
```

client.get_guild will load the discord guild data into memory same as the Guild.get_member.
You just have to fetch them with id's of guilds/members you want to target.

Comment: Alr man, thanks!

Comment: Note that you may need to use [`await guild.fetch_member()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_member) if the member is not cached by the bot.

Comment: Alr, thx! Yeah the get_guild returns a NoneType even though the value is an int and presences are on

Comment: In the newest discord.py version on GitHub you can use `discord.Object(any_discord_related_id)`, it will return the object associated with that id. In your case member and/or role.